# Changing the margins on Bootstrap 3 for container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a site utilizing the bootstrap framework and I want to change the outside margins that are default for Bootstrap's '.container' class.

I want the margins narrower on the outsides, and I want to not have it jump to different sizes based on screen/resolution (For those who use Bootstrap, when the screen gets to a certain size .container class automatically jumps to a different set of margins.)

I just want a consistent margin throughout that I can set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply override the CSS. However, you should avoid modifying the Bootstrap files directly, as that limits your ability to update the library. Place your own, custom CSS after Bootstrap, and modify it however you choose.

Further, try using SASS or LESS and creating a variable for your margins/padding. Then you can reuse the variable for various breakpoints or custom containers, and have a single point to edit the margins/padding later.

Another good idea is to modify your containers with a custom class, so that the original styles are preserved. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container.custom-container {
      padding: 0 50px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
  Here's a normal container
</div>

<div class="custom-container container">
  Here's a custom container
</div>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with SASS or LESS, just a beginner. prob is I tried using .container { margin: 0 10px; } but it shifted it all to the left

Comment: I'm not sure if you're talking about margins or padding. The way you're explaining it sounds like padding is the issue. The .container class has left and right margins set to auto, which is how it is centered for the medium breakpoint and above. If you override the left/right margins with 10px, as you're saying above, you will destroy that centering effect.

Comment: I'd also say that a big appeal of using Bootstrap is having it handle various screen sizes gracefully. If that doesn't interest you, you may not want to use the framework to begin with, and simply write your own CSS.

Comment: Bootstrap works great except if your site has a lot of block elements. at some screen sizes the 'blocks' will go right to the edge of the window, then one pixel smaller and it jumps to 100px padding on the sides. I use it more for the .column features

Comment: so your usage is extending container class of bootstrap, in another words, custom-container inherits from container, right?

Comment: @batmaci that's one way of thinking about it... but keep in mind CSS operates via specificity rules, with more specific rules taking precedence over less specific. So, in the example setting additional CSS within the `.container.custom-container` block, has the capacity of overriding styles set by Bootstrap to the `.container` class.

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 9):

In bootstrap 4, `container-fluid` gives a full-width container

Answer (score 0):

Create a css file of your own and attach it after boostrap.css (dont override the default css), and change whatever you want (include *!important* to your attribute if needed).

- About narrow the outside, change '*padding-left*' and '*padding-right*' of class ***container*** (or ***container-fluid***) to fit your will (default to both padding is 15px)
- To fix the width of the web, you can include '***width: 1000px***' (or whtever number (percent) you want) to '***container***' class